# Jupyter has 0 active kernels (Anaconda with Python 2.7)

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Anaconda 2.5 w/Python 2.7. Upon launching jupyter (which is bundled in Anaconda), the python kernel isn't being detected.

The web server launches and listens on 8888. The browser notebook editor works fine. However, I can't run any python code. The "Cell" menu isn't appearing.

Is there a configuration file or something that needs to be installed?

Here's the output from the console:

```
[I 21:32:27.625 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\smilesydney
[I 21:32:27.625 NotebookApp] **0 active kernels**
[I 21:32:27.625 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 21:32:27.627 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Comment: You should start a kernel from http://localhost:8888/tree interface. You should see a 'New' dropdown menu (upper right area) and you should have, at least, the "Python 2" kernel there.

Comment: When you open or create a notebook, does it tell you that the kernel has died or anything? What browser are you using, and can you try in another one?

Comment: Thanks kikocorreoso - I had incorrectly assumed that one could open existing .py files and run them. But you actually need to create a notebook and then paste the code to execute into it.

Answer (score 4):

The default port 8888 is blocked, I think. 
For single launch this should help:

```
jupyter notebook --port=8889
```

To fix that permanently run:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then go to *./anaconda/* directory and add

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.port = 8889
```

to file *jupyter_notebook_config.py*

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! `jupyter notebook --port=8889` fixed my problem <3

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that through upgrading the Jupyter in Anaconda.

See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2382 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Reinstalling ipython solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Simply restart the jupyter notebook solved the problem for me.

If one restart doesn't help, restart it again.