# Jupyter notebook not working 0 active kernels - MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to the apple mac family and currently on OSX El Capitan 10.11.5 . 
I've installed anaconda frame work, when I type

`jupyter notebook
OR
jupyter notebook --port=8889`

in the terminal the following appears - 

`[W 12:50:17.219 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
[I 12:50:17.435 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 1 kernels found
[I 12:50:17.760 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 12:50:17.760 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
[I 12:50:17.764 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 12:50:17.824 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 12:50:17.848 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/paawan
[I 12:50:17.848 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 12:50:17.848 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/
[I 12:50:17.848 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).`

(with few port changes in the two commands. Also important thing to observe is that it says 0 active kernels)
And I'm directed to browser where the following can be seen in traditional style -

ERROR:The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost:8888/tree

Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.

I've tried all possible solutions from -

[Jupyter has 0 active kernels (Anaconda with Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681391/jupyter-has-0-active-kernels-anaconda-with-python-2-7)

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/297

But still the issue persists or some other pops up.
Also I've tried to make it work through pip but there also some or the other mac related issues occur -

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

[OSX El Capitan: sudo pip install OSError: [Errno: 1] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted)

Please help. I'm in desperate need.